# Magento 2 Write to CSV within Controller

Tags: magento2, controllers, csv

I have the following code:

```
protected $_fileSystem;
protected $_directoryList;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList
) {
    $this->_fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    $this->_directoryList = $directoryList;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute(){
    $this->writeToCSV();
}

private function writeToCSV(){

    try{
        $media = $this->_fileSystem->getDirectoryWrite($this->_directoryList::MEDIA);
        $media->writeFile('text.txt', 'test');
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be writing anything to the text file that exists within the same folder as the controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try Following way,

```
<?php

protected $filesystem;
protected $directoryList;
protected $csvProcessor;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    )
{
    $this->filesystem = $filesystem;  
    $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
    $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
}

function writeToCsv(){
    $fileDirectoryPath = $this->directoryList->getPath(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);

    if(!is_dir($fileDirectoryPath))
        mkdir($fileDirectoryPath, 0777, true);
    $fileName = 'export.csv';
    $filePath =  $fileDirectoryPath . '/' . $fileName;

    $data = [];
      /* pass data array to write in csv file */
    $data[] = ['orderid' => '100001'];
    $this->csvProcessor
        ->setEnclosure('"')
        ->setDelimiter(',')
        ->saveData($filePath, $data);

    return true;
}
```

You can check your generated CSV file inside **var** folder

Comment: I'll give it a whirl. Thanks again Rakesh, always super fast at answering questions.

Comment: Just a quick question about the directory path. Do I carry on from \Magento\Framework\App\ as though I was in the app folder? So in my case code\company\module?

Comment: my path is **var** directory you can set your path

Comment: @RakeshDonga, How can I collect customer wishlist data and download as a CSV file? Please help me

Comment: @RakeshDonga crystal clear answer.. :)